# Problem in Include file

Tags: c++

I want to write two program(.h and .cpp) with below code and use .h file in .cpp but when i run it in TC occur below error

**.h File**

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H

int add(int x, int y)
{
     return x + y;
}

#endif
```

**.cpp file**

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Add.h"

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    cout << "Sum of 3 and 4 :" << add(3, 4);
    getch();
}
```

**Error**

> Unable to open include file "Add.h"

Comment: Are you certain you have saved the header file as Add.h in the same directory as the .cpp file?

Comment: Did you name the .h file Add.h or add.h or other case chnages. Ig not are they in the same directory and wha twas the command used to compile them

Comment: What platform/compiler? Linux file names are case sensitive, may be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things you should look into:

- the location (search path) of header files is implementation dependent, both for the `<>` and `""` variants - make sure your header file is in that path somewhere.
- you *may* find that you need to use `add.h` (all lowercase).
- you shouldn't generally include code in header files (you should put it in a separate C file and just use the header file to list declarations (or the prototype in your case).
- if that's Turbo C you're using (and it probably is, given the `clrscr` and `getch`), there's really no excuse not to upgrade to a more modern environment.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to add `-I.` flag to you compile line.

Answer (score 0):

Add.h is not in the includes path of your compiler.

By the way, `iostream.h` is deprecated, you should include `iostream`. Also, `cout` is in the `std` namespace, so you need a `using namespace std;` in your .cpp file or, alternatively, use `std::cout` instead of `cout`.

Comment: Yes, iostream.h _is_ deprecated but, if this is Turbo C, I suspect you won't get a choice :-)

Comment: Oh well, then the only real answer would be "upgrade your compiler" :-)